# Utimaco HSM integration with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hardware-security-module

Can anybody please suggest the possible solution for Utimaco HSM and spring boot application integration.

i have gone through several suggestions and utimaco official website, but i could not get the clear cut solution.

if there is no API available in Utimaco and Spring boot side, atleast with java latest version also will ok for my requirement.

I need some detais of suitable simulators to test and save my secure information in the simulators.

and in on-primise what is the best option to replace.

and in cloud as well how to integrate and use.

any help could be great achievement for my project.

Comment: You want the standard SecurityServer simulator.  Don't put production artifacts into the Simulator, it's a simulator, not an HSM.  For the HSM, it depends on the performance window -- what are you targeting, HTTPS? Application data encryption? Once you have that, it doesn't matter if its on-prem/hybrid or a managed service in the cloud.  They all talk the same protocol, so the libraries don't care if its the sim, or a physical HSM (PCIe or Appliance).  

Does Spring know what an HSM is?

Comment: how it is different whether it is https or Applicatio data encryption.

Comment: https is ssl key agreement offload (the https secret key is in the HSM) -- data-in-motion.  Application data encryption is data-at-rest (RDBMS TDE) and/or data-in-use, (manipulation of plain text data only happens inside the HSM, ie PIN translations or register math)